# Voximplant(очередь звонков)

Tags: javascript, sip

Пытаюсь разобраться с Voximplant, мне необходимо реализовать звонок от пользователя к оператору, причем если оператор занят то пользователь остановился в очередь и не снимался с линии если сам не прервет связь. Ознакомился с [документацией](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/) но ничего подобного не нашел, реально ли подобное реализовать при помощи Voximplant если нет..."ткните" в каком направлении мне нужно двигаться дабы реализовать данный функционал звонков.

P.S. Звонки должны быть бесплатными

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сценарий "колл центр" хорошо описан вот в этом цикле статей: https://voximplant.com/docs/howto/#callcenter

Звонки бесплатны, если идет Peer-to-Peer коммуникация. К примеру, звонок из Web SDK и оператор тоже использует Web SDK. Или из мобильного приложения на мобильное приложение. Если в процессе звонка участвуют операторы связи, то вряд ли получится сделать бесплатно, так как они берут деньги за услуги организации этой самой связи.